# How can I get similar distribution from different groups?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-science

I've to find in the dataset subgroups with similar average for 2 metrics than my original group.

For example, I'd like to find a city or group of cities with the closest `average(metric 1) = 10` and `average(metric 2) = 5`.

Dataset example:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: what the answer of your example? is NYC of 1/1/2019 the most similar one? I have an idea but I want ensure that I understood very well

Comment: can you post the data as text please, images are highly discouraged when posting data

Answer (score 2):

Just group by cities and then sort by closes value (I've just added two metric columns, hope that it is ok as I have no details what metric is)

```
df2 = df.groupby(['city']).mean()

input1 = 10
input2 = 5

df_sort = df2.iloc[((df2['metric 1']-input1)+(df2['metric 2']-input2)).abs().argsort()]
```